# What is the difference between fsck options -y and -p?

Tags: ext4, ext3, fsck, ext2

The ext2/3/4 filesystem checker has two options that seem to be very similar, `-p` and `-y`.

Both *seem* to perform an automatic repair, but the manpage states that `-p` can exit when it encounters certain errors while for `-y` no such thing is mentioned. Is this the only difference?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a specific difference which when we read it twice might make more sense.

```
-p - Automatically repair the file system without any questions.
-y - Assume an answer of `yes' to all questions.
```

So `fsck -p` will try to fix the file system automatically without any user intervention. It is most likely to take decisions such as **yes** or **no** by itself.

However, `fsck -y` will just assume **yes** for all questions.

An example can be thought like,

If some changes need to be made in a partition, `fsck -y` will just go ahead and assume **yes** and make the changes.

However, `fsck -p` will take the correct decision which can be either **yes** or **no**.

Comment: Actually `fsck` cannot make a *correct* decision (not even admins can in all cases); instead if chooses the presumably *safer* choice, and if it cannot decide what to do you still need to do a manual repair (delegating the decision to a human). In contrast `-y` will guarantee to exit  with a "consistent" filesystem in more cases, possibly loosing some files that could be saved. To the safety hierarchy most likely is: (1) manual repair, (2) `-p`, (3) `-y` Some people don't care and just use `-y`, however.

Comment: Let's say I have no idea how to "manually repair" a filesystem.. I mean.. are there books about that stuff or does it take like 10 years to learn anyways?